# dynamic class name for reflection in c#

Tags: c#, class, reflection

I have a class :

```
Class MyClass
{
...
}
```

I need to get the type of the class in order to use it in reflection:

```
string className="MyClass";
var type1=Type.GetType(className, true); //I have a problem loading the class here.
```

Comment: if you see [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5cf8k43(v=vs.110).aspx): _typeName: The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See [AssemblyQualifiedName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx). If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace._

Comment: You don't necessarily have to save the type name in a string. See my answer, and please clarify if there are requirements not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need the name, you can directly do:

```
var type1 = typeof(MyClass);
```

Comment: OP want save typename in string, and in this case your variant not work

Comment: @Grundy the OP says "I need to get the type of the class in order to use it in reflection".  There may not be a requirement to save the typename in a string.

Comment: I'll agree with Eren on this one, it just seems like OP thought it was the only way.

Comment: I not thought about it :-) i think that just many types in string and trying work with it :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use [Type Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type_properties.aspx)

```
typeof(T).Name
```

and if you are dealing with instance then

```
this.GetType().Name
```